# Add a net registry key in msi using orca

Tags: windows-installer, orca

I added to add reg key in msi Registry table but when I try to install msi file ,reg key is not updated in registry location  and below message in log Component: maxvalue ; Installed: Null how ever msi installed without reg key.

Can someone help ?

Regards
Babu

I received msi file from vendor and I want to add a registry key in msi using orca tool

Comment: Please add more information that makes it easy for others to reproduce your issue! Best would be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At least show us, what you have tried. Which key, name, value did you add etc.